# LetsEncrypt siteExtension The ACME server was probably unable to reach

Tags: azure-web-app-service, lets-encrypt

I am using Let'sEncrypt site extension for auto-renewal of ssl cert for my Azure web apps. It's been working fine the past few times. however today renewal got this error:

```
[03/05/2018 01:00:43 > 34472d: INFO] The ACME server was probably unable to reach http://{site url}/.well-known/acme-challenge/J62tq8vE6U2m3kA2YQRZEI0kHF8lrVq-I6bNF5BkOBc
[03/05/2018 01:00:43 > 34472d: INFO] AzureLetsEncryptRenewer.exe Error: 0 : Unable to reach http://{site url}/.well-known/acme-challenge/J62tq8vE6U2m3kA2YQRZEI0kHF8lrVq-I6bNF5BkOBc
[03/05/2018 01:00:43 > 34472d: INFO] 
[03/05/2018 01:00:43 > 34472d: INFO] Check in a browser to see if the answer file is being served correctly.
[03/05/2018 01:00:43 > 34472d: INFO] AzureLetsEncryptRenewer.exe Error: 0 : Encountered exception: System.Exception: The Lets Encrypt ACME server was probably unable to reach http://{site url}/.well-known/acme-challenge/J62tq8vE6U2m3kA2YQRZEI0kHF8lrVq-I6bNF5BkOBc view error report from Lets Encrypt at https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/mnuyRxfxxfBkVGA3iYKiC_2LaHLm7rSXgrnw42irjXU for more information
[03/05/2018 01:00:43 > 34472d: INFO]    at LetsEncrypt.Azure.Core.Services.BaseHttpAuthorizationChallengeProvider.<Authorize>d__5.MoveNext()
```

I tried to access the /.well-known/acme-challenge/ myself but couldn't access it either. I check the permission and it's granted for public read.

Any suggestion to fix this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work. You can also try to use the App Service Editor that is in preview as well as I was able to make the folder with it but below is what I did:

1. Use WinSCP to connect to the Azure Web App’s FTP and not FileZilla
2. Create the directly “.well-known” - **note that the folder may not show up in the FTP client**
3. Select Go To option in WinSCP ( right click on empty space or use toolbar on FTP side) to navigate inside the folder by typing out the
   path: ***/site/wwwroot/.well-known***
4. Create the **acme-challenge** folder
5. Place the verification file
6. Create a web.config file as below and upload.
7. Verification should now go throug

web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
         <staticContent>
             <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/xml" />
         </staticContent>
     </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```